# Hi, Trying to extract names + e-mail from a text file and don't know how to put the output next to each other

Tags: python, extract

I'm trying to get my data to output side by side, name and e-mail. Right now it just prints the e-mails and then the names.

**Here's my code:**

```py
import re
import nltk
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
stop = stopwords.words('english')

inputfile = open('/Users/jchome/Downloads/StockXRF/untitled.txt','r')
string = inputfile.read()



def extract_email_addresses(string):
    r = re.compile(r'[\w\.-]+@[\w\.-]+')
    return r.findall(string)

def ie_preprocess(document):
    document = ' '.join([i for i in document.split() if i not in stop])
    sentences = nltk.sent_tokenize(document)
    sentences = [nltk.word_tokenize(sent) for sent in sentences]
    sentences = [nltk.pos_tag(sent) for sent in sentences]
    return sentences

def extract_names(document):
    names = []
    sentences = ie_preprocess(document)
    for tagged_sentence in sentences:
        for chunk in nltk.ne_chunk(tagged_sentence):
            if type(chunk) == nltk.tree.Tree:
                if chunk.label() == 'PERSON':
                    names.append(' '.join([c[0] for c in chunk]))
    return names

if __name__ == '__main__':
    emails = extract_email_addresses(string)
    names = extract_names(string)


print (emails + names)
```

**output:**

`['1lawrencenage1l@gmail.com', george@gmail.com, 'Lawrence', 'George']`

How can I put the output next to each other and write to a text file?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to iterate through two lists in parallel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1663807/how-to-iterate-through-two-lists-in-parallel)

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like:

```
import pandas as pd
zipped = list(zip(emails, names))
df = pd.DataFrame(zipped, columns = ['emails' , 'names'])
```

After this you are able to print the dataframe and you can use e.g. the [to_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) method to save the output to a file.

Comment: getting this error:                                                                                               
   Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/Temp/stockxnltk4.py", line 41, in <module>
    df = pd.DataFrame(zipped, columns = ['emails' , 'names'])
NameError: name 'pd' is not defined

Comment: You need to import pandas first to use this function.
'import pandas as pd' should fix your problems ;)